# Why routes are deleted using VLP16 and RVIZ?

Tags: ros, rviz, vlp16, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

We are trying to visualize in realtime the VLP-16 data in RVIZ.

Our config :

- Ubuntu 14.04
- ROS indigo
- Velodyne VLP-16

We launch in several terminals these following commands :

TTY0 :

```
$ sudo route add 192.168.1.201 eth0
$ roscore
```

TTY1 :

```
$ roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud VLP16-points.launch
```

TTY2 :

```
$ rosrun velodyne_pointcloud cloud_node _calibration:=($mypath)/VLP16db.yaml
```

TTY3 :

```
$ rosrun rviz rviz -f velodyne
```

We can see it real time for like a few minutes, and then it freezes.

When we look at the `route -n` command the velodyne route (192.168.1.201) is gone.

After this, if we enter the : `sudo route add 192.168.1.201 eth0` command again, rviz shows data correctly in realtime.

Any ideas why the route disappears ?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235992/why-routes-are-deleted-using-vlp16-and-rviz-?/) by [ArthurAlear](https://answers.ros.org/users/27019/arthuralear/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2016-06-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-03**:
Is your machine a DHCP client? Could be that it's flushing the routes upon renewal of the lease. Check `syslog` or `dmesg` to see whether the 'loss of route' coincides with lease renewal.

Also: have you checked to see whether the route disappears when you're not running anything from ROS?

**Comment by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) on 2016-06-03**:
Why are you running two instances of the cloud_node? VLP16-points.launch runs everything (including the cloud_node as a nodelet).

https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/blob/master/velodyne_pointcloud/launch/VLP16_points.launch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. @kmhallen is right: don't run the cloud node, because `VLP16-points.launch` already starts the cloud nodelet. Since they are both publishing the same information to the `/velodyne_points` topic, the result will be confusing and waste cycles and bandwidth.
2. The recommended method is to attach the Velodyne to its own ethernet port with a statically assigned IP in the `192.168.1.x` range. We normally do it via the Ubuntu network manager like this:

- IP address: `192.168.1.77`
- netmask: `255.255.255.0`
- gateway: `192.168.1.0`

Setting up a VLP-16 is very similar to [this 32E tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20HDL-32E#Connect_to_the_LIDAR). We'd like to make a VLP-16 version of that tutorial some time soon.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ArthurAlear](https://answers.ros.org/users/27019/arthuralear/) on 2016-06-20**:
Thanks for your answer !